# MySQL Select of Time column returns a datetime.timedelta object in python

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

MySQL table has a column Start_Time which is defined as Time and has values  that look like 07:00:00, 08:00:00, 09:15:00 etc

Select Start_Time from foo returns a datetime.timedelta object in the results set, whilst I was expecting a datetime.time object

I'm using Python 3.4.2, MySql 5.7.17, and pymysql to join the two.

Whilst I can convert this to a datetime.time by adding it to a datetime object where I have set the time part to 00:00:00.0, and then using .time(), this does seem a little long winded!!